# Adjusting date column in data.frame with differing weekdays to consistent Day of Week

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a set of tennis rankings for a player by date

```
date <- as.Date(c("1973-08-23","1973-09-13","1973-09-26","1973-10-15","1973-10-31"))
ranking <- c(1,2,3,3,1)
df <- data.frame(date,ranking)

        date ranking
1 1973-08-23       1
2 1973-09-13       2
3 1973-09-26       3
4 1973-10-15       3
5 1973-10-31       1
```

They are roughly every fortnight but differ by day

```
library(lubridate)
wday(df$date) # [1] 5 5 4 2 4
```

I want to create a data.frame(df2) based on the data above so that the ranking is shown weekly for each Monday. The result would be

```
         date ranking
1  1973-08-27       1
2  1973-09-03       1
3  1973-09-10       1
4  1973-09-17       2
5  1973-09-24       2
6  1973-10-01       3
7  1973-10-08       3
8  1973-10-15       3
9  1973-10-22       3
10 1973-10-29       3
11 1973-11-05       1

wday(df2$date) # [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

This is somewhat simplified as there would be a PlayerA, PlayerB etc for all the ranks

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideal solution would be the `data.table` join with `roll=Inf`

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(date=seq.Date(from=as.Date("1973-08-27"), to=as.Date("1973-11-05"), by=7))
setkey(setDT(df), date)
setkey(df1, date)
df[df1, roll=Inf]
#          date ranking
# 1: 1973-08-27       1
# 2: 1973-09-03       1
# 3: 1973-09-10       1
# 4: 1973-09-17       2
# 5: 1973-09-24       2
# 6: 1973-10-01       3
# 7: 1973-10-08       3
# 8: 1973-10-15       3
# 9: 1973-10-22       3
#10: 1973-10-29       3
#11: 1973-11-05       1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
weekly_ranks <- function(df) {
  date <- df[,1]
  rank <- df[,2]
  start <- if(wday(min(date)) <= 2)     
  {min(date) +2-wday(min(date))
  } else {min(date) + 9-wday(min(date))} 
  end <- max(date)
  mondays <- seq(start, end, by=7)
  ranks <- match(as.character(cut(mondays, date)), as.character(date))
  data.frame(date=c(mondays, end), 
           ranking=c(rank[ranks], rank[df$date == end]))
}

weekly_ranks(Player_A)
#          date ranking
# 1  1973-08-27       1
# 2  1973-09-03       1
# 3  1973-09-10       1
# 4  1973-09-17       2
# 5  1973-09-24       2
# 6  1973-10-01       3
# 7  1973-10-08       3
# 8  1973-10-15       3
# 9  1973-10-22       3
# 10 1973-10-29       3
# 11 1973-10-31       1
```

For all of the players at once, you can do:

```
lst <- list(Player_A, Player_B, Player_C)
lapply(lst, weekly_ranks)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an empty data frame of the desired size. Then you make a for loop where you run through this new data frame, and fill it with the latest available ranking. You fetch him the next line every time there is a new ranking.

To make it clearer:

```
j=1
   for(i in 1:length(output[,1])){
      if(as.numeric(output[i,1])>as.numeric(input[j,1])){
         j=j+1
      }
   output[i,2:10] = input[j,2:10]
}
```

where `output` is an array with as many lines as there are Mondays, and as many columns as there are players (+1 for the dates)